# Test-Net issue / Ethereum Wallet,

Tags: wallets

I dowloaded the Ethereum Wallet, version 0.7.3 for Mac.

I used the address on the main account, and the ethers that I sent 
to the wallet from shapeships, are not there. I can' text the Test-Net
I did a new installation, but again and again the test- net is present 
can you please help me with this. thank you,
Frank

Answer (score 2):

The ethereum you got from shapeshift is not availble on the test-net. You have to use the regular EVM . Connect to the regular Homestead network and you should be able to find your ETH. You can also try to check your balance in ethchain.org